# How to set the name property of spark State declaratively to a string variable value

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, mxml

I have spark States declared in mxml. I also have a class with string constants. I want my states names to match the string constants. Is it possible to do that directly in mxml and how? 
I don't want to use the same string, I want to set the name property to the constant's value.

code:

```
public static const create:String = 'create';
public static const edit:String = 'edit';
```

mxml:

```
<s:State name="new"/>
<s:State name="edit"/>
```

As far as I know state names need to be processed at compile time so probably it's not possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the problem is you cannot include constants in state declarations :(